# How to use mongoexport with query script file

Tags: mongodb, mongoexport

I'm trying to follow this tutorial: http://www.ultrabug.fr/tag/mongoexport/

and use a sh file for the query line.
this is my file:

```
#!/bin/bash
d=`date --date="-3 month"`
echo "{ timeCreated: { "\$lte": $d} }"
```

this is my mongoexport line:

```
 mongoexport --db game_server --collection GameHistory -query /home/dev/test2.sh --out /home/dev/file.json
```

I keep getting:

```
assertion: 16619 code FailedToParse: FailedToParse: Expecting '{': offset:0 of:/home/dev/test2.sh
```

why? How can I make this work?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found several errors in your approach, let's examine them one by one.

### Date format

MongoDB expects date to be a number or [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) string.

Unfortunately, unix `date` utility have no build-in support for this format, so you should use:

```
d=`date --date="-3 month" -u +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ"`
```

### Using extended JSON

JSON specification have no support for dates, so you should use [MongoDB extended JSON](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/#date). So, your final query should look like this:

```
{ "timeCreated": { "$lte": { "$date": "2014-05-12T08:53:29Z" } } }
```

### `test.sh` output

You messed up with quotation marks. Here is a script example, outputting correct JSON:

```
#!/bin/bash
d=`date --date="-3 month" -u +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ"`
echo '{ "timeCreated": { "$lte": { "$date": "'$d'" } } }'
```

### Passing query to `mongoexport`

`mongoexport` expects `--query` to be a JSON string, not `.sh` script. So, when you're passing file path to `--query`, `mongoexport` expects it to be a JSON file.

To fix it you should execute `test2.sh` yourself and pass resulting string to `mongoexport`:

```
mongoexport --db game_server --collection GameHistory \
  --query "`./test2.sh`" --out ./test2.json
```

**N.B.** Notice `"` quotation marks around `./test2.sh` call. They're telling bash to treat `./test2.sh` output as a single parameter, ignoring all inner quotation marks and whitespaces.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add back ticks around a script or command to have it evaluated:

```
 mongoexport --db game_server --collection GameHistory \
 -query `/home/dev/test2.sh` --out /home/dev/file.json
```